# Why is my query uses filtering instead of index cond when I use an `OR` condition?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, performance, indexing

I have a `transactions` table in PostgreSQL with `block_height` and `index` as `BIGINT` values. Those two values are used for determining the order of the transactions in this table.

So if I want to query transactions from this table that comes after the given `block_height` and `index`, I'd have to put this on the condition

- If two transactions are in the same `block_height`, then check the ordering of their `index`
- Otherwise compare their `block_height`

For example if I want to get 10 transactions that came after `block_height 100000` and `index 5`:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE (
  (block_height = 10000 AND index > 5)
  OR (block_height > 10000)
)
ORDER BY block_height, index ASC
LIMIT 10
```

However I find this query to be extremely slow, it took up to 60 seconds for a table with 50 million rows.

However if I split up the condition and run them individually like so:

```
SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE block_height = 10000 AND index > 5 
ORDER BY block_height, index ASC
LIMIT 10
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM transactions 
WHERE block_height > 10000
ORDER BY block_height, index ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Both queries took at most `200ms` on the same table! It is much faster to do both queries and then `UNION` the final result instead of putting an `OR` in the condition.

This is the part of the query plan for the slow query (OR-ed condition):

```
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.98..11689726.68 rows=68631 width=73) (actual time=10230.480..10234.289 rows=10 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using src_transactions_block_height_index on src_transactions  (cost=0.56..3592792.96 rows=16855334 width=73) (actual time=10215.698..10219.004 rows=1364 loops=1)
              Filter: (((block_height = $1) AND (index > $2)) OR (block_height > $3))
              Rows Removed by Filter: 2728151
```

And this is the query plan for the fast query:

```
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..52.62 rows=1 width=73) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
        ->  Index Scan using src_transactions_block_height_index on src_transactions  (cost=0.43..22.22 rows=5 width=73) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((block_height = $1) AND (index > $2))
```

I see the main difference to be the use of `Filter` instead of `Index Cond` between the query plans.

Is there any way to do this query in a performant way without resorting to the `UNION` workaround?

Comment: `or` often kills the use of indexes.  What can I say?  Get used to it.  You understand one work-around which is to use separate subqueries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that block_height is compared to two different parameters which you know just happen to be equal might be a problem.  What if you use $1 twice, rather than $1 and $3?

But better yet, try a tuple comparison

```
WHERE (block_height, index) > (10000, 5)
```

This can become fast with a two-column index on `(block_height, index)`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, I didn't know you can do tuples comparison. Using this comparison my query runs just in 190ms on the same table.